# Apply multiple functions at one time to Pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Variations of this question have been asked (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532024/pandas-apply-multiple-functions-of-multiple-columns-to-groupby-object)) but I haven't found a good solution for would seem to be a common use-case of `groupby` in Pandas.

Say I have the dataframe `lasts` and I group by `user`:

```
lasts = pd.DataFrame({'user':['a','s','d','d'],
                   'elapsed_time':[40000,50000,60000,90000],
                   'running_time':[30000,20000,30000,15000],
                   'num_cores':[7,8,9,4]})
```

And I have these functions I want to apply to `groupby_obj` (what the functions do isn't important and I made them up, just know that they require multiple columns from the dataframe):

```
def custom_func(group):
    return group.running_time.median() - group.num_cores.mean()

def custom_func2(group):
    return max(group.elapsed_time) -min(group.running_time)
```

I could `apply` each of these functions separately to the dataframe and then merge the resulting dataframes, but that seems inefficient, is inelegant, and I imagine there has to be a one-line solution.

I haven't really found one, although this [blog post](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_apply_operations_to_groups.html) (search for "Create a function to get the stats of a group" towards the bottom of the page) suggested wrapping the functions into one function as a dictionary thusly:

```
def get_stats(group):
    return {'custom_column_1': custom_func(group), 'custom_column_2':custom_func2(group)}
```

However, when I run the code `groupby_obj.apply(get_stats)`, instead of columns I get *a* column of dictionary results:

```
user
a    {'custom_column_1': 29993.0, 'custom_column_2'...
d    {'custom_column_1': 22493.5, 'custom_column_2'...
s    {'custom_column_1': 19992.0, 'custom_column_2'...
dtype: object
```

When in reality I would like to use a line of code to get something closer to this dataframe:

```
user custom_column_1    custom_column_2
a    29993.0                10000
d    22493.5                75000
s    19992.0                30000
```

Suggestions on improving this workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would slightly modify the `get_stats` function:

```
def get_stats(group):
    return pd.Series({'custom_column_1': custom_func(group),
                      'custom_column_2':custom_func2(group)})
```

now you can simply do this:

```
In [202]: lasts.groupby('user').apply(get_stats).reset_index()
Out[202]:
  user  custom_column_1  custom_column_2
0    a          29993.0          10000.0
1    d          22493.5          75000.0
2    s          19992.0          30000.0
```

---

Alternative (bit ugly) approach which uses your functions (unchanged):

```
In [188]: pd.DataFrame(lasts.groupby('user')
                            .apply(get_stats).to_dict()) \
            .T \
            .rename_axis('user') \
            .reset_index()
Out[188]:
  user  custom_column_1  custom_column_2
0    a          29993.0          10000.0
1    d          22493.5          75000.0
2    s          19992.0          30000.0
```

Comment: IMHO Wrapping the dictionary in a Series is the best solution to this question of the three you've presented. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following approach:

```
funcs = {
  'running_time': {'rt_med':'median', 'rt_min':'min'},
  'num_cores': {'nc_avg':'mean'},
  'elapsed_time': {'et_max':'max'}
}

x = lasts.groupby('user').agg(funcs)
x.columns = x.columns.droplevel(0)

formulas = """
custom_column_1 = rt_med - nc_avg
custom_column_2 = et_max - rt_min

"""

res = x.eval(formulas, inplace=False).drop(x.columns, 1).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
In [145]: res
Out[145]:
  user  custom_column_1  custom_column_2
0    a          29993.0            10000
1    d          22493.5            75000
2    s          19992.0            30000
```

**Explanation (step by step):**

```
In [146]: x = lasts.groupby('user').agg(funcs)

In [147]: x
Out[147]:
     running_time        num_cores elapsed_time
           rt_med rt_min    nc_avg       et_max
user
a           30000  30000       7.0        40000
d           22500  15000       6.5        90000
s           20000  20000       8.0        50000

In [148]: x.columns = x.columns.droplevel(0)

In [149]: x
Out[149]:
      rt_med  rt_min  nc_avg  et_max
user
a      30000   30000     7.0   40000
d      22500   15000     6.5   90000
s      20000   20000     8.0   50000

In [150]: x.eval(formulas, inplace=False)
Out[150]:
      rt_med  rt_min  nc_avg  et_max  custom_column_1  custom_column_2
user
a      30000   30000     7.0   40000          29993.0            10000
d      22500   15000     6.5   90000          22493.5            75000
s      20000   20000     8.0   50000          19992.0            30000

In [151]: x.eval(formulas, inplace=False).drop(x.columns, 1)
Out[151]:
      custom_column_1  custom_column_2
user
a             29993.0            10000
d             22493.5            75000
s             19992.0            30000

In [152]: x.eval(formulas, inplace=False).drop(x.columns, 1).reset_index()
Out[152]:
  user  custom_column_1  custom_column_2
0    a          29993.0            10000
1    d          22493.5            75000
2    s          19992.0            30000
```