# Python pandas: mean and sum groupby on different columns at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like the following:

```
Name    Missed    Credit    Grade
A       1         3         10
A       1         1         12      
B       2         3         10
B       1         2         20
```

And my desired output is:

```
Name    Sum1   Sum2    Average
A       2      4      11
B       3      5      15
```

Basically to get the sum of column `Credit` and `Missed` and to do average on `Grade`. What I am doing right now is two groupby on `Name` and then get sum and average and finally merge the two output dataframes which does not seem to be the best way of doing this. I have also found this on SO which makes sense if I want to work only on one column:

```
df.groupby('Name')['Credit'].agg(['sum','average'])
```

But not sure how to do a one-liner for both columns?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by `dictionary` and then `rename` columns names:

```
d = {'Missed':'Sum1', 'Credit':'Sum2','Grade':'Average'}
df=df.groupby('Name').agg({'Missed':'sum', 'Credit':'sum','Grade':'mean'}).rename(columns=d)
print (df)
      Sum1  Sum2  Average
Name                     
A        2     4       11
B        3     5       15
```

If want also create column from `Name`:

```
df = (df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)
       .agg({'Missed':'sum', 'Credit':'sum','Grade':'mean'})
       .rename(columns={'Missed':'Sum1', 'Credit':'Sum2','Grade':'Average'}))
print (df)
  Name  Sum1  Sum2  Average
0    A     2     4       11
1    B     3     5       15
```

Solution with named aggregations:

```
df = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).agg(Sum1=('Missed','sum'), 
                                            Sum2= ('Credit','sum'),
                                            Average=('Grade','mean'))
print (df)
  Name  Sum1  Sum2  Average
0    A     2     4       11
1    B     3     5       15
```

Comment: in the last command, is it possible to add a custom function ?

Comment: @Basile - sure, use instead `Average=('Grade','mean')` e.g. `Average=('Grade','my _function')` and then `def my_function(x): return x.cumsum().mean()` or  `Average=('Grade',lambda x: x.cumsum().mean())`

Answer (score 3):

```
A = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Name':['A','A','B','B'],'Missed':[1,1,2,1],'Credit':[3,1,3,2],'Grades':[10,12,10,20]})

A.groupby('Name').agg({'Missed':'sum','Credit':'sum','Grades':'mean'})
```