# Pandas groupby with custom functions on each column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

[image: DF]

Given this df, how can I apply a pandas groupby with custom functions for each column such that the resulting dataframe looks like this?
[image]

Also, some other ids have multiple seasons over many years, so is there any way to capture the change in value over the seasons?

Comment: Please make your examples copy-pastable, thanks.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate:  [Apply multiple functions to multiple groupby columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns)

Comment: I'm not sure SO supports tables