# Understanding resampling of datetime in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a question regarding resampling of DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['2005-01-20', 10], ['2005-01-21', 20], 
                   ['2005-01-27', 40], ['2005-01-28', 50]],
                   columns=['date', 'num'])

# Convert the column to datetime 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Resample and aggregate results by week
df = df.resample('W', on='date')['num'].sum().reset_index()

print(df.head())
# OUTPUT: 
#         date  num
# 0 2005-01-23   30
# 1 2005-01-30   90
```

Everything works as expected, but I would like to better understand what exactly `resample()`,`['num']` and `sum()` do here.

**QUESTION #1**

Why the following happens:

The result of `df.resample('W', on='date')` is `DatetimeIndexResampler`.

The result of `df.resample('W', on='date')['num']`  is `pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy`.

The result of `df.resample('W', on='date')['num'].sum()` is

```
date
2005-01-23    30
2005-01-30    90
Freq: W-SUN, Name: num, dtype: int64
```

**QUESTION #2**

Is there a way to produce the same results without resampling? For example, using `groupby`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer1**

1. As the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) says, `.resample` returns a `Resampler` Object. Hence you get `DatetimeIndexResampler` because `date` is a datetime object.
2. Now, you get `<pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy` because you are looking for `Series` from the dataframe based of off the `Resampler` object.

   Oh by the way,

   `df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-SUN')])['num']`
   Would return
   `<pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy` as well.
3. Now when you do [`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), you are getting the sum over the requested axis of the dataframe. You get a `Series` because you are doing sum over the `pandas.core.series.Series`.

**Answer2**

You can achieve results using `groupby` with the help from [Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) as follow:

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-SUN')])['num'].sum()
```

Output:

```
date
2005-01-23    30
2005-01-30    90
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do we retrieve columns at step 2 that we previously grouped by `date`? If we retrieve multiple columns, not only `num`, can we use different aggregation methods like `sum()` and `mean()`  for different columns?

Comment: @Konstantin, yes, you can as many as columns as you need. Apply `.sum()` or `.mean()`. For example, if you had some another column like `val`. You get the some using `df.resample('W', on='date')[['num', 'val']].sum()` for both the columns.

Comment: But is it possible to use `.sum()` for one of them and `.mean()` for another?

Comment: @Konstantin, absolutely. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns

Comment: @Konstantin Glad to help. Happy coding.