# Pandas, Apply Custom Function to Data Grouped by String Indices

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have data I want to group by city and day (separate columns) and calculate a new value using the remaining columns.  More specifically, the other columns are counts of people by race, for 6 races.  Therefore, I have 8 columns, the two grouping ones and the 6 I want to summarize.  I want to summarize them by calculating the entropy 
 per city-day.

However, city and day are strings, and my entropy function does not like that.  It works when the grouping columns are int64.  I have tried to convert the city and day columns to dummy variables, but the error remains.

Borrowing from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns), below is an example using my function that works.

```
# The function
def newEntropy(x):
    A = x

    pA = A / A.sum()
    Shannon2 = -np.nansum(pA * np.log2(pA))

    return Shannon2

# Make fake data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,5), columns=list('abcde'))
df['group'] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
df['group2'] = [6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]

# Works
df.groupby(['group', 'group2']).apply(newEntropy)

# Having an index column that is a string causes failure
df['group2'] = df['group2'].astype('str')
df.groupby(['group', 'group2']).apply(newEntropy)
```

I need to figure out how to make newEntropy work.  It seems like it should ignore the grouping columns, but that is not the case.  I would also prefer not to convert 'group2' to int64 because in my real data it is 'YYYY-MM-DD'.  My data's equivalent of 'group1' is also a country name, which I prefer to keep as strings.

I should say that I can make a new dataframe that is the grouping that I want and then apply newEntropy to that.  It would just be nice to have something more concise, it feels like it should be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How abut specific the column you want to `apply` the `function` after `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['group', 'group2'])[list('abcde')].apply(newEntropy)
Out[191]: 
group  group2
0      6         6.057044
       7        -0.000000
1      7         4.485942
2      7         4.879091
       8         3.727744
       9        -0.000000
3      9         4.751447
4      9        -0.000000
       10        8.993928
5      10        4.191522
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  One slight modification: df.groupby(['group', 'group2'])[list('abcde')].agg('sum').apply(newEntropy)