# pandas groupby get aggregation on a column and group size into a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `df`,

```
code    y_m       day_1     day_2
13      201906    30        40
13      201906    10        20
14      201903    20        40
14      201903    20        30
```

I want to create a column

```
df['delta'] = df['day_2'] - df['day_1']

code    y_m       day_1     day_2    delta
13      201906    30        40       10 
13      201906    10        20       10
14      201903    20        40       20
14      201903    20        30       10
```

then `groupby` `code` and `y_m`, sum the delta and get the group size into another dataframe at the same time; but

```
df.groupby(['code', 'y_m']).size().reset_index(name = 'count')
```

only get the group size; so how to get aggregated `delta` as well into the same dataframe;

```
code    y_m       delta    count
13      201906    20        2
14      201903    30        2
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['code', 'y_m']).delta.agg(['sum','count'])
`

Comment: You can use `df.groupby(['code', 'y_m']).agg({'delta':['sum', 'count']})`

Comment: Also possible duplicate of

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns