# Turn repeat entries associated with different values into one entry with list of those values?

Tags: python, pandas

I wasn't sure how to title this.

Assume the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
    Student ID      Class   
1   John    99124   Biology
2   John    99124   History
3   John    99124   Geometry
4   Sarah   74323   Physics
5   Sarah   74323   Geography
6   Sarah   74323   Algebra
7   Alex    80045   Trigonometry
8   Alex    80045   Economics
9   Alex    80045   French
```

I'd like to reduce the number of rows in this DataFrame by creating a list of classes that each student is taking, and then putting that in the "class" column. Here's my desired output:

```
    Student ID      Class
1   John    99124   ["Biology","History","Geometry"]
2   Sarah   74323   ["Physics","Geography","Algebra"]
3   Alex    80045   ["Trigonometry","Economics","French"]
```

I am working with a large DataFrame that is not as nicely organized as this example. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure a list is really the ideal solution. Storing objects in a DataFrame just creates an obstacle for most future manipulations. For instance, it's no longer trivial to check which students have taken `Biology`, or at least not without a much less performant method.

Comment: @ALollz do you recommend an alternative approach?

Comment: It depends what kind of manipulations you need in the end. Having a long format where each row is a unique key (as in the above) can be useful and is flexible. It's not difficult to `pivot`, or get dummies from there, which might be more suitable for other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `Student` and `ID` and then use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html).

```
df.groupby(['Student', 'ID'], as_index=False).agg({'Class': list})
```

Ouput:

```
  Student     ID                              Class
0    Alex  80045  [Trigonometry, Economics, French]
1    John  99124       [Biology, History, Geometry]
2   Sarah  74323      [Physics, Geography, Algebra]
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks for the quick and accurate response.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('ID')['Class'].apply(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

let's see, using some help 
[Apply multiple functions to multiple groupby columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns)

you could write something like

```
df= df.groupby('student').agg({'id':'max', 'Class': lambda x: x.tolist()})
```

hope it helps, giulio

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
df.groupby(['Student', 'ID'],as_index=False).agg(lambda x:','.join('"'+x+'"'))
```