# groupby apply function does not handle more than one function

Tags: python, pandas

I have this datafarme:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'cn':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 'date': ['01/10/2017', '02/09/2016', '02/10/2016','01/20/2017', '05/15/2017', '02/10/2016', '02/10/2018'],
     'score':[4,10,6, 5, 15, 7, 8]})

    cn  date    score
0   1   01/10/2017  4
1   1   02/09/2016  10
2   1   02/10/2016  6
3   1   01/20/2017  5
4   2   05/15/2017  15
5   2   02/10/2016  7
6   2   02/10/2018  8
```

I have these two functions:

```
def total_count_phq9_BOF_activation (grf):
    s = grf.score.count()
    return s

def first_phq9_BOF_activation (grf):
    value =grf[grf.score==grf.score.max()].date
    return value
```

I used this solution (1) to use these two functions for the apply method:

```
df.groupby('cn').apply (lambda x: pd.Series({"first_phq9_BOF_activation": first_phq9_BOF_activation , "total_count_phq9_BOF_activation": total_count_phq9_BOF_activation}))
```

But it did not work. Would you please let me know what part of my code is wrong?

[Apply multiple functions to multiple groupby columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns)

Comment: you should do `agg`: `df.groupby('cn').agg([first_phq9_BOF_activation, total_count_phq9_BOF_activation ])`

Comment: Did you try it? it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call function `total_count_phq9_BOF_activation` and `first_phq9_BOF_activation` inside Series constructor.They are not part of `apply`. They belong to series constructor, so you need specifically call them with `(x)`

```
df.groupby('cn').apply (lambda x: pd.Series({"first_phq9_BOF_activation": first_phq9_BOF_activation(x) , 
                                             "total_count_phq9_BOF_activation": total_count_phq9_BOF_activation(x)}))

Out[157]:
                    first_phq9_BOF_activation  total_count_phq9_BOF_activation
cn
1   1    02/09/2016
Name: date, dtype: object                                4
2   4    05/15/2017
Name: date, dtype: object                                3
```

Comment: L, thank you. the function "first_phq9_BOF_activation" also prints other things "date, dtype, ..." how can change the function so that it do not print it.

Comment: it returns `s` and `s` is a series itself.  `Name: date, dtype:...` is part of every series. In the current implementation of `first_phq9_BOF_activation`, you can't get rid of them. Perhaps, there is another way, but you need editing and adding your desired output to the question to show what output you want

Comment: L, I fixed this function (def first_phq9_BOF_activation (grf):
    value =grf[grf.score==grf.score.max()].date
    return value) by adding min() to the date. So it is def first_phq9_BOF_activation (grf):
    value =grf[grf.score==grf.score.max()].date.min()
    return value)