# Categorize and print information from vectors

Tags: python, sorting, vector

I am beginner in programming, so I don't understand a lot of Python, I have a code that takes information from a CSV file:

```
23;1;42.8
21;1;....
```

So what I thought was that the information is easier to manage in vectors,  so I made this code:

```
import csv

with open("city_traffic.csv") as file_csv:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file_csv, delimiter=';')

    cities=[]
    for line in csv_reader: 
        new_list=[]
        i=int(line[0])
        k=int(line[1])
        j=float(line[2])
        new_list.append(k)
        new_list.append(i)
        new_list.append(j)      

        cities.append(new_list)

    for s in cities:
        print("City: "+str(s[0])+ ". Total Amount of Traffic: "+str(s[2])+ ". Rush Hour: "+str(s[1]))
```

And the output is like:

```
City: 1. Total Amount of Traffic: 42.8. Rush Hour: 23
City: 1. Total Amount of Traffic: 89.1. Rush Hour: 21
City: 4. Total Amount of Traffic: 60.5. Rush Hour: 2
City: 4. Total Amount of Traffic: 50.6. Rush Hour: 10
City: 3. Total Amount of Traffico: 44.2. Rush Hour: 10
```

My question, is there a way that I can categorize or sort the info so I can add the total amount of traffic of each city and then show which hour is the one with the most traffic, for example:

```
City: 1 Total Amount of Traffic: 131.9 Rush Hour: 21
City: 4 Total Amount of Traffic: 111.1 Rush Hour: 2
City: 3 Total Amount of Traffic: 44.2 Rush Hour: 10
```

As you can see I don't have any code for this last part, I have been struggling with this issue, but I would appreciate any advices on how to do it, or maybe improving my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `pandas` for this. It has many useful functions which don't need to use `for`-loop

At start you can read it and add column names in one line of code (if you don't count `import`)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('city_traffic.csv', sep=';', names=['Rush', 'City', 'Traffic'])
```

And you can display it

```
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Rush  City  Traffic
0    23     1     42.8
1    21     1     89.1
2     2     4     60.5
3    10     4     50.6
4    10     3     44.2
```

It has also functions to display only some columns or rows

```
print(df[ df['City'] == 1 ])
```

Result:

```
   Rush  City  Traffic
0    23     1     42.8
1    21     1     89.1
```

Or if you need to use `for`-loop

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(f"City: {row['City']}. Total Amount of Traffic: {row['Traffic']}. Rush Hour: {row['Rush']}")
```

Result:

```
City: 1.0. Total Amount of Traffic: 42.8. Rush Hour: 23.0
City: 1.0. Total Amount of Traffic: 89.1. Rush Hour: 21.0
City: 4.0. Total Amount of Traffic: 60.5. Rush Hour: 2.0
City: 4.0. Total Amount of Traffic: 50.6. Rush Hour: 10.0
City: 3.0. Total Amount of Traffic: 44.2. Rush Hour: 10.0
```

Using `pandas` you can group by `City` and sum `Traffic`

```
groups = df.groupby('City')

print(groups['Traffic'].sum())
```

Result:

```
City
1    131.9
3     44.2
4    111.1
Name: Traffic, dtype: float64
```

In groups for different columns you can run different functions: `sum` for `Traffic` and `min` for `Rush`

```
new_df = groups.agg({'Traffic': 'sum', 'Rush': 'min'})
new_df = new_df.reset_index()

print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
   City  Traffic  Rush
0     1    131.9    21
1     3     44.2    10
2     4    111.1     2
```

---

Minimal working code .

I use `io.StringIO` in `read_csv()` only to simulate file in memory but you should use `read_csv('city_traffic.csv', ...)`

```
text ='''23;1;42.8
21;1;89.1
2;4;60.5
10;4;50.6
10;3;44.2'''

import pandas as pd
import io

#df = pd.read_csv('city_traffic.csv', sep=';', names=['Rush', 'City', 'Traffic'])
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep=';', names=['Rush', 'City', 'Traffic'])

print(df)
print('---')

print(df[ df['City'] == 1 ])
print('---')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(f"City: {row['City']}. Total Amount of Traffic: {row['Traffic']}. Rush Hour: {row['Rush']}")
print('---')


groups = df.groupby('City')

print(groups['Traffic'].sum())
print('---')


new_df = groups.agg({'Traffic': 'sum', 'Rush': 'min'})
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
print(new_df)
print('---')

#new_df['City'] = new_df['City'].replace({1:'Berlin', 4:'Paris', 3:'Roma'})
new_df['City'] = ['Berlin', 'Paris', 'Roma']
print(new_df)
print('---')

for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
    print(f"City: {row['City']:6} | Total Amount of Traffic: {row['Traffic']:6.2f} | Rush Hour: {row['Rush']:2}")
print('---')
```

Result:

```
   Rush  City  Traffic
0    23     1     42.8
1    21     1     89.1
2     2     4     60.5
3    10     4     50.6
4    10     3     44.2
---
   Rush  City  Traffic
0    23     1     42.8
1    21     1     89.1
---
City: 1.0. Total Amount of Traffic: 42.8. Rush Hour: 23.0
City: 1.0. Total Amount of Traffic: 89.1. Rush Hour: 21.0
City: 4.0. Total Amount of Traffic: 60.5. Rush Hour: 2.0
City: 4.0. Total Amount of Traffic: 50.6. Rush Hour: 10.0
City: 3.0. Total Amount of Traffic: 44.2. Rush Hour: 10.0
---
City
1    131.9
3     44.2
4    111.1
Name: Traffic, dtype: float64
---
   City  Traffic  Rush
0     1    131.9    21
1     3     44.2    10
2     4    111.1     2
---
     City  Traffic  Rush
0  Berlin    131.9    21
1   Paris     44.2    10
2    Roma    111.1     2
---
City: Berlin | Total Amount of Traffic: 131.90 | Rush Hour: 21
City: Paris  | Total Amount of Traffic:  44.20 | Rush Hour: 10
City: Roma   | Total Amount of Traffic: 111.10 | Rush Hour:  2
---
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [pandas Dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). They're great for dealing with tabular data.
As for the exact operation you would want to use grouby and apply functions as described at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns).