# Pandas - how to add multiple conditional columns to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So what I'm trying to do is create several calculations based on conditions and add them to a dataframe. Here is some code as an example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Project':  ['Project 1', 'Project 2', ' Project 3', 'Project 4', 'Project 5', 'Project 6', 'Project 7', 'Project 8', 'Project 9', 'Project 10'],
        'Date': ['10/1/2020', '10/1/2020', '11/1/2020', '12/1/2020', '12/1/2020', '12/1/2020', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '4/1/2021'],
       'Team': ['Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 2', 'Team 2', 'Team 2', 'Team 1', 'Team 1', 'Team 1', 'Team 1'],
       'Timely': ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes']})
                                       
df1=data.groupby('Team')['Timely'].apply(lambda x: (x=='Yes').sum()).reset_index(name='Yes Count')       

df1
```

Running this code will give me a table that shows the count of projects with timely = Yes for each team. Say I wanted to add a second column to the table to show the total count where timely = no and a third and fourth column to show the percent yes and percent no for each team. How would I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply multiple functions to multiple groupby columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns)

Comment: Almost. I tried using the function in the apply example on that page: ```def f(x):
    d = {}
    d['Timely'] = data['Timely'].apply(lambda x: (x=='Yes').sum())
    d['Untimely'] = data['Timely'].apply(lambda x: (x=='No').sum())
    return pd.Series(d, index=['Timely', 'Untimely'])

df.groupby('Team').apply(f)``` but got the following error: ```'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like you just want a crosstab. It's more straightforward to calculate using `pd.crosstab` than it is using a `groupby/apply` approach. Though `pd.crosstab` isn't the most efficient method of doing this, it works just fine.

This first snippet gets us the counts of "yes" and "no" for each team. We also get a "Total" column that is the sum of the "yes" + "no":

```
xtab = pd.crosstab(data["Team"], data["Timely"], margins=True, margins_name="Total")

print(xtab)
Timely  No  Yes  Total
Team                  
Team 1   1    4      5
Team 2   2    2      4
Team 3   1    0      1
Total    4    6     10
```

Now let's calculate the percentage breakdown of "No" and "Yes" by dividing those both by our "Total" column:

```
norm_xtab = xtab[["No", "Yes"]].div(xtab["Total"], axis=0)

print(norm_xtab)
Timely   No  Yes
Team            
Team 1  0.2  0.8
Team 2  0.5  0.5
Team 3  1.0  0.0
Total   0.4  0.6
```

Then we can combine those two dataframes horizontally with the `pd.concat` function. We can also give names to each "subdataframe" e.g. one chunk of the dataframe will only be for count data, the other chunk will be for the normalized/percentage based data:

```
out = pd.concat([xtab, norm_xtab], keys=["count", "percent"], axis=1)
out = out.rename(columns={"No": "untimely", "Yes": "timely"}, level=1)


print(out)
          count               percent       
Timely untimely timely Total untimely timely
Team                                        
Team 1        1      4     5      0.2    0.8
Team 2        2      2     4      0.5    0.5
Team 3        1      0     1      1.0    0.0
Total         4      6    10      0.4    0.6
```

The result of the concatenation is a DataFrame with a multiindex as the columns. If you are unfamiliar with pd.MultiIndex, you can use this snippet to flatten your result into something you may be more familiar with:

```
out.columns = ["{}_{}".format(*colname) for colname in out.columns]

print(out)

        count_untimely  count_timely  count_Total  percent_untimely  percent_timely
Team                                                                               
Team 1               1             4            5               0.2             0.8
Team 2               2             2            4               0.5             0.5
Team 3               1             0            1               1.0             0.0
Total                4             6           10               0.4             0.6
```

To change the column names as in your comment below, you can simply run `rename` one more time:

```
out = out.rename(columns=lambda colname: colname.replace("count_", ""))

print(out)
        untimely  timely  Total  percent_untimely  percent_timely
Team                                                             
Team 1         1       4      5               0.2             0.8
Team 2         2       2      4               0.5             0.5
Team 3         1       0      1               1.0             0.0
Total          4       6     10               0.4             0.6
```

To convert the decimals to whole percentages, you'll need to multiply by 100, then either round to 0 decimal places OR use string formatting to trim the trailing decimals (I'll show you how to do both), and add another string formatting to get the "%" to appear.

```
percentages = (out
               .filter(like="percent")      # select columns that contain the string "percent"
               .mul(100)                    # Multiply everything by 100
               .round(0)                    # If you don't want to perform any rounding, get rid of this line
               .applymap("{:.0f}%".format)) # Apply string formatting to trim the decimal.

print(percentages)
       percent_untimely percent_timely
Team                                  
Team 1              20%            80%
Team 2              50%            50%
Team 3             100%             0%
Total               40%            60%
```

If you want these values reflect back in our `out` dataframe:

```
out.loc[:, percentages.columns] = percentages

print(out)
        untimely  timely  Total percent_untimely percent_timely
Team                                                           
Team 1         1       4      5              20%            80%
Team 2         2       2      4              50%            50%
Team 3         1       0      1             100%             0%
Total          4       6     10              40%            60%
```

Comment: So when I try to create the second dataframe on my real dataset I get the following error: ```Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (8, 2): given (8, 1)``` Does this mean there are null values in the data set? And is there a limit on how many dataframes I can concatenate? There are two other metrics I need to include in this dataframe.

Comment: Can you show me the code that leads to the error in your case? I'm not certain which piece of code you're referring to

Comment: I can't use the code from my real data set, but I get the same error with your code with this dataframe. The first xtab code works. It's the second norm_xtab code : ```norm_xtab = xtab[["No", "Yes"]] / xtab[["Total"]].values

print(norm_xtab)```  that returns the following error: ```Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (4, 2): given (4, 1)```

Comment: Try this instead, my pandas version is `1.1.1` so a version difference might result in an error, this approach should be a little more robust. `norm_xtab = xtab[["No", "Yes"]].div(xtab["Total"], axis=0)

Comment: I have one final question. Is there a straightforward way to rename the columns in the combined crosstab and reorder the columns? So for example, instead of it saying count_no, count_yes, it would instead say untimely and timely?

Comment: Yep! Just updated my answer. You can use the `rename(columns=...)` method to do this. Note that I used `rename` twice, once right after using `pd.concat` and once at the end to strip away the "count_" prefix.

Comment: Nice that works. How many dataframes can I concat together?

Comment: You can concatenate any number of dataframes together, all you need is a list of dataframes. If you use `axis=1` it will stick them together horizontally, and `axis=0` sticks them together vertically.

Comment: Cool. Also, in your example I would like to convert the percentage to a whole number (ie., 20%"). I used the following code to do that: ```YOY = YOY.round(decimals=2) * 100  
YOY = YOY.astype(str)  + "%"```. But that results in trailing numbers after the decimal. How can I remove the decimal and trailing numbers? I'm having trouble doing that since this is a string with the % sign.

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if it's what you wanted!