# How do I sum and average rows for a panel dataset in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am confused as to how I can sum rows together and also average rows too. For my data, it is a panel from **2007** to **2013** for a `set of districts in India`.

The pictures below describe my data.

[image]

[image]

For my data, I want to add all the columns except **Rural Literacy Rate**, but I wish to add them according to each year. So I would like the 2007 values to be added to 2007 values, 2008 to 2008, and so on. I wish to add the **Adilabad district** values to the **Anantapur district** values. Lastly, for Rural Literacy Rate, I wish to average the values, but in the same way by year by year. I tried grouping but I became lost because I was not able to group by year.

Comment: do `df.head(5).to_dict()` and include that in your question, instead of images. Please see this link for more help on how to create a MRE (minimum reproducible example): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

Here's some different ways to do this using `groupby`.

**Method 1**

Use the `.agg` method to apply different functions to the different columns.

```
d = {}
for col in df.columns.drop(['State', 'District', 'Rural Literacy Rate']):
    d[col] = 'sum'
d['Rural Literacy Rate'] = 'mean'
gb = df.groupby('Year')
gb.agg(d)
```

**Method 2**

Slice according to columns, use built-in aggregation methods and then concatenate

```
sum_cols = df.columns.drop(['State', 'District', 'Rural Literacy Rate']):
mean_cols = ['Rural Literacy Rate']
gb = df.groupby('Year')
pd.concat(gb[sum_cols].sum(), gb[mean_cols].mean(), axis=1)
```

**Method 3**

Slice according to columns, use `.apply` and then concatenate

```
import numpy as np

sum_cols = df.columns.drop(['State', 'District', 'Rural Literacy Rate']):
mean_cols = ['Rural Literacy Rate']
gb = df.groupby('Year')
pd.concat(gb[sum_cols].apply(np.sum), gb[mean_cols].apply(np.mean), axis=1)
```

All three methods lead to the same column names, although it could be helpful to rename them to indicate the aggregations that were performed.

Method 1 and 3 are nice because you can use other functions besides the standard built-in aggregations (sum, count, mean, etc).

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns), you can wrap this all up in a custom function and use `.apply`, which has the added benefit of giving the columns added names at the same time.

Comment: Many many many thanks! This helps a lot and I appreciate the detail you gave!

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider upvoting or selecting as preferred answer if it meets your needs.