# How do i aggregate a dataframe and apply a lambda function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a data frame with the following columns:

- id
- name
- product
- count
- price
- discount

and i want to create a sumamry data frame where it shows the sum of how much each client has spend total. with and without discount applied.

i tried the following

```py
summary = df.groupby('client_name')['price','count','discount'].agg([
    ('Total pre discount', df['price']*df['count']),
    ('Discount applied', df['price']*df['count']*df['discount']
])
```

and im getting this error:

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

is it even possible to do this in one step?

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Please note that `agg()` function cannot be used for calculation involving multiple columns. You have to use `apply()` function instead.  Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns) for details.

> if you had multiple columns that needed to interact together then you
> cannot use agg, which implicitly passes a Series to the aggregating
> function. When using apply the entire group as a DataFrame gets passed
> into the function.

For your case, you have to define a customized function as follows:

```
def f(x):
    data = {}
    data['Total pre discount'] = (x['price'] * x['count']).sum()
    data['Discount applied'] = (x['price'] * x['count'] * x['discount']).sum()
    return pd.Series(data)
```

Then perform your desired task by:

```
df.groupby('client_name').apply(f)
```

or if you want to use lambda function instead of customized function:

```
df.groupby('client_name').apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'Total pre discount':  (x['price'] * x['count']).sum(), 'Discount applied': (x['price'] * x['count'] * x['discount']).sum()}))
```

### Run Demonstration

***Test Data Creation***

```
data = {'id': ['0100', '0200', '0100', '0200', '0300'], 'client_name': ['Ann', 'Bob', 'Ann', 'Bob', 'Charles'], 'product': ['pen', 'paper', 'folder', 'pencil', 'tray'], 'count': [12, 300, 5, 12, 10], 'price': [2.00, 5.00, 3.50, 2.30, 8.20], 'discount': [0.0, 0.1, 0.15, 0.1, 0.12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

Output: 
      id    client_name product count   price   discount
0   0100            Ann     pen    12     2.0       0.00
1   0200            Bob   paper   300     5.0       0.10
2   0100            Ann  folder     5     3.5       0.15
3   0200            Bob  pencil    12     2.3       0.10
4   0300        Charles    tray    10     8.2       0.12
```

***Run New Codes***

```
# Use either one of the following 2 lines of codes:
summary = df.groupby('client_name').apply(f)     # Using the customized function f() defined above
# or using lambda function
summary = df.groupby('client_name').apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'Total pre discount':  (x['price'] * x['count']).sum(), 'Discount applied': (x['price'] * x['count'] * x['discount']).sum()}))

print(summary)

Output:

               Total pre discount   Discount applied
client_name     
        Ann                  41.5              2.625
        Bob                1527.6            152.760
    Charles                  82.0               9.84
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['client', 'discount']).agg({'price' : 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Hey, could you pls explain your code? Wasn't able to understand how it works? ty!

Comment: No problem. It will group by both the client name and discount, then sum the prices for each (your column names might be slightly different, I took these from the bullet points you put at the top of your question).