# Pandas Implement Equation & Groupby 2 Conditions

Tags: pandas, group-by, calculation

I have data that looks like this below and I'm trying to calculate the CRMSE (centered root mean squared error) by site_name and year. Maybe i need an agg function or a lambda function to do this at each groupby parameters (plant_name, year). The dataframe data for df3m1:

```
     plant_name  year  month  obsvals  modelvals  
0     ARIZONA I  2021      1     8.90       8.30  
1     ARIZONA I  2021      2     7.98       7.41  
2     CAETITE I  2021      1     9.10       7.78  
3     CAETITE I  2021      2     6.05       6.02
```

The equation that I need to implement by plant_name and year looks like this:

```
crmse = df3m1.groupby(['plant_name','year'])((  (df3m1.obsvals - df3m1.obsvals.mean())  - 
(df3m1.modelvals - df3m1.modelvals.mean())  ) ** 2).mean() ** .5
```

This is a bit advanced for me yet on how to integrate a groupby and a calculation at the same time. thank you. Final dataframe would look like:

```
  plant_name   year   crmse
0 ARIZONA I    2021     ?
1 CAETITE I    2021     ?
```

I have tried things like this with groupby -

```
crmse = df3m1.groupby(['plant_name','year'])((  (df3m1.obsvals - 
df3m1.obsvals.mean())  - (df3m1.modelvals - df3m1.modelvals.mean())  ) 
** 2).mean() ** .5
```

but get errors like this:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` is correct. After that, we would have used `.agg` normally, but computing csrme interacts with multiple columns (`obsvals` and `modelvals`). So we pass the entire dataframe then take columns as we want by using `.apply`.

Code:

```
def crmse(x, y):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square( (x - x.mean()) - (y - y.mean()) )))

def f(df):
    return pd.Series(crmse(df['obsvals'], df['modelvals']), index=['crmse'])

crmse_series = (
    df3m1
    .groupby(['plant_name', 'year'])
    .apply(f)
)

crmse_series 
                 crmse
plant_name year       
ARIZONA I  2021  0.015
CAETITE I  2021  0.645
```

---

You can *merge* the series into the original dataframe with `merge`.

```
df = df.merge(crmse_series, on=['plant_name', 'year'])
df
  plant_name  year  month  obsvals  modelvals  crmse
0  ARIZONA I  2021      1     8.90       8.30  0.015
1  ARIZONA I  2021      2     7.98       7.41  0.015
2  CAETITE I  2021      1     9.10       7.78  0.645
3  CAETITE I  2021      2     6.05       6.02  0.645
```

---

See Also:

- [Apply multiple functions to multiple groupby columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns)

Comment: this is great, i'm not sure i understand it and how do i assign the output to a new df? Thank you!

Comment: ok, i've saved the output to a variable no problem. could you explain your answer in the 3 sections iff you have a minute?