# Pandas dataframe group by column and apply different functions to different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with duplicates, and I would like for a given column to sum the values of the duplicates and for another column calculate the mean of the duplicates. The picture below illustrates what I want to achieve.

[image]

I would like something this

```
df1.groupby(["A", "B"], as_index=False){"C": sum ,"D": mean}
```

I checked this solution [Apply multiple functions to multiple groupby columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns) but the output structure is not what I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're missing an `agg()` method after `groupby`. Also, community can address your question better if you could update your question with a sample data.

Comment: `df1.groupby(["A", "B"], as_index=False).agg({"C": "sum", "D": "mean"})` Missing agg, missing quotations around aggregate functions

Answer (score 1):

As @ashkangh recommended, you could use the agg() function. Something like this
df.duplicated().groupby().agg(mean, sum).