# Groupby by sum of revenue and the corresponding highest contributing month - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a bill details data set and I want to do a groupby of the products based on the sum of their Total value, additionally i want a column which indicates the month which has produced the most revenue for the corresponding product

Data set:

```
Bill_Id  Month  Product_Id  Net_Value
 1        1       20          100
 2        1       20          100
 3        2       20          100
 4        1       30          200
 5        2       30          200
 6        2       30          200
```

Desired_Result

```
Product_Id  Total_revenue  Top_Month
   20          300            1
   30          600            2
```

This just a sample dataset I have the transaction data of the entire year

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add the code you have come up with to your question?

Comment: In your question on what basis the top month value 1 or 2 is being decided ? Is it based on frequency ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pivot the dataframe with `aggfunc=sum`, then use `sum` and `idxmax` along columns axis to find total revenue and month which has the highest contribution to total revenue, finally `concat` the individual components along column axis to get the result

```
s = df.pivot_table('Net_Value', 'Product_Id', 'Month', aggfunc='sum')
pd.concat([s.sum(1), s.idxmax(1)], axis=1, keys=['Total_revenue', 'Top_Month'])
```

---

```
            Total_revenue  Top_Month
Product_Id                          
20                    300          1
30                    600          2
```

Comment: Amazing, didn't know that pivot data can also be summed after generating, Thanks :)

Comment: @Alonso Glad to know you find this helpful. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your only 1 Top month value is needed based on the maximum sum of Net_Revenue, Below is the code that might work for you.

We can achieve this in 3 stages as mentioned below:

###### 1. Extracting the sum of net revenue based on product id

```
df_1 = df.groupby(['Product_Id']).agg({'Net_Value' : sum}).reset_index()
df_1 = df_1.rename(columns={'Net_Value' : 'Total_revenue'})

print(df_1)
Product_Id  Total_revenue
0   20  300
1   30  600
```

###### 2. Extracting the best contibuting month based on max sum net revenue for each product id

```
df_2 = df.groupby(['Product_Id', 'Month']).agg({'Net_Value' : sum}).sort_values('Net_Value', ascending=False).reset_index()
df_2 = df_2.drop_duplicates(subset=['Product_Id'])[['Product_Id', 'Month']]

print(df_2)
Product_Id  Month
0   30  2
1   20  1
```

###### 3. Final step is to merge this both dataframes into single based on product id

```
final_df = df_1.merge(df_2)

print(final_df)
Product_Id  Total_revenue  Month
0          20            300      1
1          30            600      2
```

Please do upvote the solution if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Small modification over @Shubham's approach

```
result = (
    df.pivot_table("Net_Value", "Product_Id", "Month", aggfunc="sum")
    .agg(["sum", "idxmax"], axis=1)
    .set_axis(["Total_revenue", "Top_Month"], axis=1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As multiple columns are being interacted, I have used the  `apply` function in addition to `groupby`:

Net_value is calucated using basic aggregate function `sum`

Top_month required interaction between columns so, first get the index of max Net_value using `idxmax` then using `loc` to find the month

The resultant Pandas Series object has the groupby column (Product_id) as index, so it make it a column I have used `reset_index`

```
def f(x):
    d = {}
    d['Net_Value'] = x['Net_Value'].sum()
    d['Top_month'] = df.loc[x['Net_Value'].idxmax(), "Month"]
    return pd.Series(d, index=['Net_Value', 'Top_month'])

df.groupby('Product_Id').apply(f).reset_index()

# Output

  Product_Id    Net_Value   Top_month
0   20             300         1
1   30             600         2
```

Check out this amazing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47103408/14090264) which helped me and can help you in the future as well.