# how to execute multiple functions in pandas groupby processing

Tags: python, pandas

I am calculating `pct_change` in pandas groupby but from the first element of each group. Hence i am using `cumprod()`. I already have a working code but it is little ugly. How can i use `pct_change()` and `cumprod()` in one liner.

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[1, 10], [2, 17], [3, 15],[4, 11], [5, 17], [6, 15]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["id", "open"])

#normal
df['Normal'] =df['open'].pct_change().fillna(0).add(1).cumprod().sub(1).mul(100).round(2)


#groupby
df["Group_of_3"] = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3 )["open"].pct_change().fillna(0).add(1)
df["Group_of_3"] = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3 )["Group_of_3"].cumprod().sub(1).mul(100).round(2)


print(df)
```

**output**

```
   id  open  Normal  Group_of_3
0   1    10     0.0        0.00
1   2    17    70.0       70.00
2   3    15    50.0       50.00
3   4    11    10.0        0.00
4   5    17    70.0       54.55
5   6    15    50.0       36.36
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you need all the intermediates?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns

Comment: @mozway I think he only needs the output

Comment: @mozway As you can see to produce column Group_of_3 i am assigning pct_change and cumprod in two different lines. Is there any way to combine. i used dot notation but output was wrong.

Comment: @prem you can use `groupby.transform`, see below

Comment: @PV8 the link you provided is a different issue, here the problem is that prem wants to keep the `groupby` during the complete transformation ;)

Comment: @PV8 yes he is right! Thanks anyways. I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly simplify the repeated code using a custom function and avoid the double `groupby`. Using [`groupby.tranform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for the second column:

```
def pct_cumprod(s):
    return s.pct_change().fillna(0).add(1).cumprod().sub(1).mul(100).round(2)

df['Normal'] = pct_cumprod(df['open'])

df['Group_of_3'] = (df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3)['open']
                      .transform(pct_cumprod)
                    )
```

If you only need the `Group_of_3` column:

```
df['Group_of_3'] = (df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3)['open']
                      .transform(lambda g: g.pct_change().fillna(0).add(1)
                                            .cumprod().sub(1).mul(100)
                                            .round(2))
                   )
```

Output:

```
   id  open  Normal  Group_of_3
0   1    10     0.0        0.00
1   2    17    70.0       70.00
2   3    15    50.0       50.00
3   4    11    10.0        0.00
4   5    17    70.0       54.55
5   6    15    50.0       36.36
```